# Java Bluetooth issue using blue cove on Debain

Tags: java, bluetooth, debian, bluecove, dragonboard

I wrote two small java programs and I was able to use Bluetooth to send messages between two laptops. I used a jar file called bluecove.
One laptop was a MAC and the other was Windows.

I tried running the same java program on a small UNIX machine running Debain
but I get the error message:

```
Native Library bluecove_aarch64 not available
Exception in thread “main” javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove library bluecove not available;
resource not found libbluecove_aarch64.so
load [bluecove_aarch64] no bluecove_aarch64 in java.library.path:[/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]`
```

I have jar files bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and [bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/bluecove/bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar) in the classpath.
I have done an install of libbluetooth-dev

The UNIX machine is DragonBoard 410C, a small computer on a chip.

Comment: I see that you can "preview" 2.1.1 ... perhaps use the same version (2.1.0) for both jar files? There could've been breaking changes between the two versions

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem, Dave? I'm having the same issue with openSUSE.

Comment: I had exactly the same error when I accidentally mixed versions 2.1.0 and 2.1.1.